# ResXFileCodeGenerator alternative for nested classes

Tags: c#, embedded-resource, t4, resx

I have a project where I store SQL scripts as separate files in a nested folder hierarchy, add the files to `SqlScripts.resx`, and then use ResXFileCodeGenerator. Here is a small sample of the resx file:

```xml
<data name="DeleteObjectA" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
  <value>ObjectA\Delete.sql;System.String,|etc|</value></data>
<data name="DeleteObjectB" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
  <value>ObjectB\Delete.sql;System.String,|etc|</value></data>
<data name="UpdateStatusObjectA" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
  <value>ObjectA\UpdateStatus.sql;System.String,|etc|</value></data>
<data name="UpdateStatusObjectB" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
  <value>ObjectB\UpdateStatus.sql;System.String,|etc|</value></data>
```

This creates a single `SqlScripts` class with four members (e.g. `SqlScripts.UpdateStatusObjectB`).

However, the more types (ObjectA, ObjectB, ObjectC), and operations (Update, Delete) I have, this becomes increasingly unmaintainable and difficult to read. I'd rather have nested classes (e.g. `SqlScripts.ObjectA.Delete`, where `ObjectA` is of type `ObjectASqlScripts`), but that's not supported in resx files.

Is it possible to generate nested classes like this from a folder hierarchy or an XML file? If so, how? (a general outline is fine.)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why would you store sql files in a resx in the first place?

Comment: @Remy Company pattern for doing database operations. Much cleaner than a giant `string` in the middle of a file.